# MySql Как высчитывать sum('sum') по user_id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

У меня `Join`  несколько таблиц по принципу `left join`.И в результате получается несколько колонок совпадающие для `user_id` и получается что сумма считается дважды.

```
SELECT 
  s.id AS s__id,
  s.user_id AS s__user_id,
  d.account_currency_id AS currency_id,
  d.platform AS d__2,
  SUM(d.amount_with_commission) AS sum
FROM
  sf_guard_user_profile s 
  LEFT JOIN sf_guard_user s2 
ON s.user_id = s2.id 
  LEFT JOIN user_promo_source u 
ON s2.id = u.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN user_summary u2 
ON s2.id = u2.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN sf_guard_user_profile_accounts s3 
ON (
  (
    s2.id = s3.user_id 
    AND s3.is_remove = 0
  )
) 
  LEFT JOIN deposit_request d 
ON (
  (
    d.account_id = s3.id 
    AND (
      d.status_id = 5 
      OR d.status_id = 8 
      OR d.withdraw_id IS NOT NULL
    )
  )
) 
  LEFT JOIN sf_guard_user_calls s4 
ON s4.user_id = s2.id 
WHERE (
s.lang = 'en'
AND (
  u2.start_reg_date >= "2016-09-01 00:00:00" 
  AND u2.start_reg_date <= "2016-09-30 23:59:59"
) 
AND s4.created_at >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00'
AND s.is_test_profile = 0 
AND (
  NOT (d.amount_with_commission IS NULL)
)
  ) 
GROUP BY d.account_currency_id,
  d.platform 
ORDER BY d__0 DESC
```

`DISTINCT` в начале SQL не помог, как исправить ситуацию, Как написать `SQL` чтобы для каждого пользователя сумма считалась однажды ?

Comment: @Mike Даже если бы группировал по `s__id` все равно существуют дублирующиеся колонки,и сумма будет заново рассчитываться для повтояющейся колонки.

Comment: Вы не привели целиком ваш запрос поэтому мне не на чем писать ответ (для ответа надо переделать join'ы, вложить их друг в друга). посмотрите мой ответ на подобный вопрос на английском. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148729/mysql-joining-related-tables-with-different-row-amounts-per-record/39149076#39149076

Comment: @Mike Я обновил вопрос и добавил SQL целиком.

Comment: @Mike У меня и так сложный запрос ,ресурсоемкий.Subquery он не потянет.мне лучше группировать на php.Думал есть какой то вариант

Comment: @Mike Ладно спасибо ,попробую через subquery.

Comment: @Mike `sf_guard_user_calls` таблица создает повторения

Comment: @Mike Щас над этим мучаюсь.Спасибо огромное.Как  ответ добавь чтоб проголосовал

Comment: Тогда чистим комментарии тут. они уже ни к чему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогам переписки запрос доведен до такого:

```
SELECT s.id AS s__id,
       s.user_id AS s__user_id,
       d.account_currency_id AS currency_id,
       d.platform AS d__2,
       SUM(d.amount_with_commission) AS sum
  FROM sf_guard_user_profile s 
  JOIN user_summary u2     ON u2.user_id = s.user_id
  JOIN sf_guard_user_calls s4 ON s4.user_id = s.user_id
  JOIN sf_guard_user_profile_accounts s3  ON s3.user_id = s.user_id AND s3.is_remove = 0
  JOIN deposit_request d ON d.account_id = s3.id AND (d.status_id in(5,8) OR d.withdraw_id IS NOT NULL)
 WHERE s.lang = 'en'
   AND u2.start_reg_date >= "2016-09-01 00:00:00" AND u2.start_reg_date <= "2016-09-30 23:59:59"
   AND s.user_id in(select user_id from sf_guard_user_calls where created_at >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00')
   AND s.is_test_profile = 0 
   AND d.amount_with_commission IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY d.account_currency_id, d.platform 
 ORDER BY d__0 DESC
```

Таблица размножавшая записи (sf_guard_user_calls) вынесена в подзапрос так как нужна была только для фильтрации по дате. Так же излишние LEFT JOIN заменены на обычные JOIN, что может облегчить жизнь оптимизатору.

Условие фильтрации может быть так же записано в виде:

```
AND EXISTS(select 1 from sf_guard_user_calls s4
            where created_at >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00' and s4.user_id = s.user_id)
```

В редких случаях это может быть быстрее, чем IN.